# Fashion MNIST code giving bag as output for every single real world image

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

Im doing a project on fashion apparel classification. I want a solution for a multiclass classification problem. Given a real world image or video relay, I need to classify the image into 3 types of classes.
Type of apparel - tshirt, trouser, pullover, dress, pillow cover, etc.
Colour of apparel - white, red, blue, etc 
Texture/material of apparel - cotton, wool, linen, satin etc.

I had to train my own models and find own database of clothes. Then I found Fashion MNIST. I have no worries on finding the colour of the cloth but having trouble for texture & type of apparel. I have to train my own cascade classifier.

Naturally, I was searching the internet for possible solutions. I found a tutorial by adrian on pyimagesearch at https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/02/11/fashion-mnist-with-keras-and-deep-learning/ 
I used his code to train my model. But Im getting bag as output for a real world image.

His montage is giving the correct output.

Images from Fashion MNIST is giving correct output, but real world images is bisased towards bag. Maybe I need image segmentation and conversion to greyscale and resizing to 28*28 to obtain the result?

Here is his code.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Agg")
from pyimagesearch.minivggnet import MiniVGGNet
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.datasets import fashion_mnist
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras import backend as K
from imutils import build_montages
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cv2

# initialize the number of epochs to train for, base learning rate,
# and batch size
NUM_EPOCHS = 25
INIT_LR = 1e-2
BS = 32

# grab the Fashion MNIST dataset (if this is your first time running
# this the dataset will be automatically downloaded)
print("[INFO] loading Fashion MNIST...")
((trainX, trainY), (testX, testY)) = fashion_mnist.load_data()

# if we are using "channels first" ordering, then reshape the design
# matrix such that the matrix is:
#   num_samples x depth x rows x columns
if K.image_data_format() == "channels_first":
    trainX = trainX.reshape((trainX.shape[0], 1, 28, 28))
    testX = testX.reshape((testX.shape[0], 1, 28, 28))

# otherwise, we are using "channels last" ordering, so the design
# matrix shape should be: num_samples x rows x columns x depth
else:
    trainX = trainX.reshape((trainX.shape[0], 28, 28, 1))
    testX = testX.reshape((testX.shape[0], 28, 28, 1))

# scale data to the range of [0, 1]
trainX = trainX.astype("float32") / 255.0
testX = testX.astype("float32") / 255.0

# one-hot encode the training and testing labels
trainY = np_utils.to_categorical(trainY, 10)
testY = np_utils.to_categorical(testY, 10)

# initialize the label names
labelNames = ["top", "trouser", "pullover", "dress", "coat",
    "sandal", "shirt", "sneaker", "bag", "ankle boot"]

# initialize the optimizer and model
print("[INFO] compiling model...")
opt = SGD(lr=INIT_LR, momentum=0.9, decay=INIT_LR / NUM_EPOCHS)
model = MiniVGGNet.build(width=28, height=28, depth=1, classes=10)
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=opt,
    metrics=["accuracy"])

# train the network
print("[INFO] training model...")
H = model.fit(trainX, trainY,
    validation_data=(testX, testY),
    batch_size=BS, epochs=NUM_EPOCHS)

# make predictions on the test set
preds = model.predict(testX)

# show a nicely formatted classification report
print("[INFO] evaluating network...")
print(classification_report(testY.argmax(axis=1), preds.argmax(axis=1),
    target_names=labelNames))

# plot the training loss and accuracy
N = NUM_EPOCHS
plt.style.use("ggplot")
plt.figure()
plt.plot(np.arange(0, N), H.history["loss"], label="train_loss")
plt.plot(np.arange(0, N), H.history["val_loss"], label="val_loss")
plt.plot(np.arange(0, N), H.history["acc"], label="train_acc")
plt.plot(np.arange(0, N), H.history["val_acc"], label="val_acc")
plt.title("Training Loss and Accuracy on Dataset")
plt.xlabel("Epoch #")
plt.ylabel("Loss/Accuracy")
plt.legend(loc="lower left")
plt.savefig("plot.png")

# initialize our list of output images
images = []

# randomly select a few testing fashion items
for i in np.random.choice(np.arange(0, len(testY)), size=(16,)):
    # classify the clothing
    probs = model.predict(testX[np.newaxis, i])
    prediction = probs.argmax(axis=1)
    label = labelNames[prediction[0]]

    # extract the image from the testData if using "channels_first"
    # ordering
    if K.image_data_format() == "channels_first":
        image = (testX[i][0] * 255).astype("uint8")

    # otherwise we are using "channels_last" ordering
    else:
        image = (testX[i] * 255).astype("uint8")

    # initialize the text label color as green (correct)
    color = (0, 255, 0)

    # otherwise, the class label prediction is incorrect
    if prediction[0] != np.argmax(testY[i]):
        color = (0, 0, 255)

    # merge the channels into one image and resize the image from
    # 28x28 to 96x96 so we can better see it and then draw the
    # predicted label on the image
    image = cv2.merge([image] * 3)
    image = cv2.resize(image, (96, 96), interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
    cv2.putText(image, label, (5, 20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75,
        color, 2)

    # add the image to our list of output images
    images.append(image)

# construct the montage for the images
montage = build_montages(images, (96, 96), (4, 4))[0]

# show the output montage
cv2.imshow("Fashion MNIST", montage)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

It will take too long everytime to execute his code. Hence I made 2 files. 1 saves the model for the  other file to use.

Here is my code part 1

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Agg")

from pyimagesearch.minivggnet import MiniVGGNet
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.datasets import fashion_mnist
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras import backend as K
from imutils import build_montages
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cv2


NUM_EPOCHS = 25
INIT_LR = 1e-2
BS = 32

print("[INFO] loading Fashion MNIST...")
((trainX, trainY), (testX, testY)) = fashion_mnist.load_data()


if K.image_data_format() == "channels_first":
    trainX = trainX.reshape((trainX.shape[0], 1, 28, 28))
    testX = testX.reshape((testX.shape[0], 1, 28, 28))

else:
    trainX = trainX.reshape((trainX.shape[0], 28, 28, 1))
    testX = testX.reshape((testX.shape[0], 28, 28, 1))


trainX = trainX.astype("float32") / 255.0
testX = testX.astype("float32") / 255.0

trainY = np_utils.to_categorical(trainY, 10)
testY = np_utils.to_categorical(testY, 10)

labelNames = ["top", "trouser", "pullover", "dress", "coat",
    "sandal", "shirt", "sneaker", "bag", "ankle boot"]

print("[INFO] compiling model...")
opt = SGD(lr=INIT_LR, momentum=0.9, decay=INIT_LR / NUM_EPOCHS)
model = MiniVGGNet.build(width=28, height=28, depth=1, classes=10)
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=opt,
    metrics=["accuracy"])

print("[INFO] training model...")
H = model.fit(trainX, trainY,
    validation_data=(testX, testY),
    batch_size=BS, epochs=NUM_EPOCHS)

model.save('fashion_mnist_model.h5')

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

part 2

```
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.preprocessing import image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os
import cv2


if __name__ == "__main__":

    # load model
    model = load_model("fashion_mnist_model.h5")

    labelNames = ["top", "trouser", "pullover", "dress", "coat",
    "sandal", "shirt", "sneaker", "bag", "ankle boot"]

    # image path
    img_path = 'tshirt.jpg'

    # load a single image
    originalimg = cv2.imread(img_path,0)
    img = cv2.resize(originalimg,(28,28))
    img = img.reshape([-1, 28, 28, 1])

    # check prediction
    pred = model.predict(img)
    print(pred)
    prediction_result = np.argmax(pred[0])
    print(prediction_result)

    label = labelNames[prediction_result]
    print(label)

    color = (0, 255, 0)

    cv2.putText(originalimg, label, (5, 20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75, color, 2)

    cv2.imshow('result',originalimg)

    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Expected to output tshirt but it classified it as bag. Change the epoch to 1 or 2 instead of 25 if you want, to quickly see whats happening.

I saw another tutorial on tensorflow. https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/basic_classification
It is also giving bag as output for real world images. Maybe it doesnt work on real world images?

Here is the code of tensorflow

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals

# TensorFlow and tf.keras
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

# Helper libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

print(tf.__version__)

fashion_mnist = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = fashion_mnist.load_data()

class_names = ['T-shirt/top', 'Trouser', 'Pullover', 'Dress', 'Coat',
               'Sandal', 'Shirt', 'Sneaker', 'Bag', 'Ankle boot']

train_images.shape

len(train_labels)

train_labels

test_images.shape

len(test_labels)


train_images = train_images / 255.0

test_images = test_images / 255.0


model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=5)

import cv2

img = cv2.imread('pant.jpg',0)

img = cv2.resize(img,(28,28))

img = img / 255.0


cv2.imshow('result',img)

img = (np.expand_dims(img,0))

predictions_single = model.predict(img)
print(predictions_single)
prediction_result = np.argmax(predictions_single[0])
print(prediction_result)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

again, bag as output instead of pant.

Comment: I think you need to train the model on your image only.

Comment: We have no idea what your data looks like, but it is generally unreasonable to expect machine learning models to work well on data that is different from what is has been trained on. E.g. maybe all your images look closest to what "bags" look like in FashionMNIST.

Answer (score 2):

Vishnu is right. For anyone watching this, you just have to do:

```
img = 255 - img
```

in order for the image to turn to negative.

Answer (score 1):

May be it is too late. But, the issue is with the difference in the training images as well as external images. In the training images, background is expressed as 0 and in most of the external images you collect from the internet, the background will be expressed as 1s.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `[0]` after `predictions_single = model.predict(img)`, like this:

```
predictions_single = model.predict(img)[0]
```